# Limit of simple improper integral

Tags: calculus

Suppose $ f(x) \ge 0 $ is integrable and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) d x = 1$.

Then my book claims that $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}\int_{-\infty}^x f(x) d x = 0$ but why is this?

Comment: Monotone or dominated convergence.

Comment: @T.Bongers I see how monotone works but might there be a simpler proof cause this is chapter 1 of a book that doesn't assume measure theory?

Comment: Added an answer down below. I'm sure you'll grasp it easily :) Make sure you approve the answer if it's the one that answer's to your question so that the thread goes down as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} f(x)dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)  - \lim_{x \to - \infty} F(X) = 1 $ where $F(x)$ is the $\int f(x)dx = F(X) $.

Then : $ \lim_{x \to - \infty} \int_{- \infty}^x f(x) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} F(X) - \lim_{x \to - \infty} (\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x)). $

But : $\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(X) = \lim_{x \to  \infty} - 1.$

So : $\lim_{x \to - \infty} \int_{- \infty}^x f(x) = \lim_{x \to - \infty} F(X) - \lim_{x \to - \infty} (\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(X) - 1 - \lim_{x \to - \infty} (\lim_{x \to \infty} F(X) - 1) = 0. $

Note that the first relationship tells us that the limits are real numbers, because their subtraction gives a real number.

Comment: what is X here? is it x?